# Не отображается поток с камеры снятый в MJPEG

Tags: jpeg, gstreamer, mjpg

Пишу приложение на gtk. Подключил виджет к вэб камере и получил фпс около одного кадра в 10 секунд.

Пытаюсь понять в чем проблема:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,framerate=25/1,width=1280,height=960 ! \
    jpegparse ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Где video0 - камера Logitech C270, которая умеет mjpeg в указанном формате.

Работает как надо с fps 25:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! jpegenc ! image/jpeg,framerate=25/1,width=1280,height=960 ! \
    jpegparse ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Тоже с заказанным fps:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,framerate=25/1,width=1280,height=960 ! \
    jpegparse ! matroskamux ! filesink location="video.mkv"
```

В дебаге льется  `videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:3298:gst_video_decoder_clip_and_push_buf:<jpegdec0> Dropping frame due to QoS.` и ничего примечательного кроме

```
0:00:00.282411963 10971 0x55a0d033d520 DEBUG             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:609:default_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> config GstBufferPoolConfig, caps=(GstCaps)"image/jpeg\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)25/1\,\ width\=\(int\)1280\,\ height\=\(int\)960\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ interlace-mode\=\(string\)progressive\,\ colorimetry\=\(string\)2:4:5:1", size=(uint)816000, min-buffers=(uint)4, max-buffers=(uint)32, allocator=(GstAllocator)"NULL", params=(GstAllocationParams)NULL;
0:00:00.282435243 10971 0x55a0d033d520 DEBUG         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:750:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> activating pool
0:00:00.282445743 10971 0x55a0d033d520 DEBUG         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:797:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> requesting 4 MMAP buffers
0:00:00.283215421 10971 0x55a0d033d520 DEBUG          v4l2allocator gstv4l2allocator.c:706:gst_v4l2_allocator_start:<v4l2src0:pool0:src:allocator> allocated 4 mmap buffers out of 4 requested
0:00:00.283344821 10971 0x55a0d033d520 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:814:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool0:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

`jpegparse` в этой связке тормозит. Переместил в другую ветку - теперь пишет и показывает нормально.